# Using Jmeter - HTML Link Parser

Tags: parsing, jmeter

Using the [HTML link parser](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser) in Jmeter.

1. I tell Jmeter to go to a page http://myserver/user_requests - where a bunch of requests are shown to the user.
2. Now I want Jmeter to go thru all the user_request links which are on that page which start with /user_requests/id - where id is that specific user_requests id

How can I accomplish step 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Link Parser is a pre-processor. By itself, it doesn't do anything.

According to the documentation you linked to in your question, you have to use it in conjunction with a Simple Controller, which has an HTTP Sampler and the Link Parser.

Layout would be:

```
testplan
-thread group
--simple controller
---HTML Link Parser
---HTTP Request Sampler
```

Set the domain on the link parser to your domain and the path as needed.

That will cause the sampler to spider the site.

I've not used this controller very much myself, but it looks like there options to limit the depth.

Answer (score 0):

use post-processor of RegularEx combined with ForEach controller.